# Java JComboBox is it possible to set editable true into one item only?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

i want to create a `JComboBox` that have a three items on it.. I want to set editable only to the last item of the `JComboBox` for example:

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();

cb.addItem("Dog");
cb.addItem("Cat");
cb.addItem("Other");
```

when i drop down the `JComboBox` and choose the item Others..`JComboBox` became editable.. how can I do that?

Comment: Make it so that `Other` pops a `JOptionPane` input dialog.  Add the item returned to the 2nd last place in the combobox model.

Comment: any sample codes there?

Comment: *"any sample codes there?"*  In that comment?  ..Do you see any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) to know which item is selected and then you can set the `JComboBox` editable as needed. Try this example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo {

      private void initGUI(){        
        Object[] items = new Object[]{"Dog","Cat","Other"};
        DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(items);        

        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(dcbm);
        comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));        
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                Object selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                boolean editable = selectedItem instanceof String && ((String)selectedItem).equals("Other");
                comboBox.setEditable(editable);
            }
        });

        /*
         * Here you can add a new item to your JComboBox when it becomes editable
         */
        comboBox.getEditor().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object newItem = comboBox.getEditor().getItem();                  
                DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm = (DefaultComboBoxModel) comboBox.getModel();
                dcbm.addElement(newItem);
                dcbm.setSelectedItem(newItem);
            }
        });

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(new JLabel("Test:"));
        content.add(comboBox);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().initGUI();
            }
        });      
    }
}
```

As you'll see, when "Other" item is selected `JComboBox` becomes editable:

[image]

Comment: how can i get the text on the other?

Comment: Just to clarify if your `JComboBox` becomes editable it doesn't mean you can "edit" the selected item value. It means you can add items to your `JComboBox` using its editor. The way to get the new string is: `comboBox.getEditor().getItem()`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo (not by me) which seems to achieve what you're after.
http://raginggoblin.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/jcombobox-with-disabled-items/

Comment: *"which seems to achieve what you're after."*  I don't think it does.  The disabled items are not use selectable and therefore cannot fire an action event.

Comment: Sorry, I need to get my eyes tested. Even after being told so by Andrew, it took me a while to realise the question was about editable and not enabling. Sorry.